# Why doesn't CartoDB display my data?

Tags: carto

I have loaded a table into CartoDB with a column for latitude, longitude, date/time and a number.

CartoDB says that the data is georeferenced by the designated columns but when I open the map, I see nothing but the base map. My data is not being displayed.

Can someone tell me some basic mistakes I might have made?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have not "georeferenced" your data correctly to make it spatially enabled.  Take a look at the [Georeferencing on CartoDB](http://developers.cartodb.com/tutorials/how_to_georeference.html) tutorial to show you how to turn your Lat/Long into spatial features.

Alternatively, perhaps you have:

1. Mapped the wrong fields (lat -> long, and long -> lat) during the georeferencing process, or
2. Have not included the correct negative signs if your data is either in the Southern Hemisphere (negative Latitude) or Western Hemisphere (negative Longitude)

Comment: The OP did mention that the data is georeferenced (at least CartoDB says so). Maybe it's lying? :)